# r.id id cannot be resolved

Tags: android

while i have programming an android program about voice recognizing i have a little problem.what is the r.id cannot be resolved i have try to change my xml files which includes res folder.it doesnt works.what can i do ?

my main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: We are not mind readers what does your code look like, post some code.

Answer (score 1):

Try cleaning your project (in Eclipse: Project->Clean...). 
If that does not fix it delete your R.java file located under the gen folder. The R.java file should be regenerated for you. 
I have done these thing to fix the problem you are describing, but your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 1):

If somewhere in your class file you have a line like this:

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);
```

then `R.id.tv1` must point to a TextView in your xml, which must first be given the id. So for example if you wanted to change the text in your TextView above you would have something like this to set the id in the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello" 

    //Set your id here:
    android:id="@+id/TEXTVIEW1"
/>
```

and then to change the text, in your class you'd have this:

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TEXTVIEW1);
tv.setText("How are you");
```

Answer (score 0):

Insert this to your xml file's view tags.

> android:id="@+id/**YOUR_VIEW_ID**"